# MongoDB library for PHP run foreach command on server

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have the following command for mongodb

```
db.products.find().forEach( 
    function(x) {
        db.autocomplete.insert({
            "_id": x.name
        });
        db.autocomplete.insert({
            "_id": x.author_name
        });
    }
);
```

Which basically creates a collection for Autocomplete/Autosuggest words.

How can I run this command with PHP? There is no build in function to du forEach commands over the library.

I know, that there is http://php.net/manual/de/mongodb.command.php, but I do not understand, how to run above command in an array structure

Comment: Use aggregation with `out` parameter.

Comment: Ok, but then I would need to run 2 seperate commands. One for `name` and one for `author_name` as `_id`, right?

Comment: It will be the simplest way. Alternatively you can employ facets.

Comment: Or you can use map-reduce

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I just added an answer based on your idea

Comment: Sorry, just realised that aggregation doesn't merge output collection like map-reduce does, but overwrites it, so consecutive calls wont work.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw it, that afterwards, there where only authors in my collection :(

Comment: Can you maybe provide an example how to do it with map-reduce? I have no idea where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but it must be something like this:

```
    $q = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
        'mapreduce' => 'products',
        'map' => 'function () { emit(this.name, 1); emit(this.author_name, 1);}', 
        'reduce' => 'function () { return null; }',
        'finalize' => 'function () {return null}',
        'out' => ['reduce' => 'autocomplete']
    ]);
```

`map` emits both name and author_name as keys with arbitrary value. `reduce` returns null, as we don't care about values. `finalize` is optional. It ensures values are null. Otherwise it may contain some residual junk.

Comment: Thank you, thats it! Just to make it correct, in the last line you used ":" instead of "=>"

Comment: Fixed. Copy-pasted from momngo shell =)